# Push Build status to GitHub

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to push the build status automatically from Azure Devops to the github repository, so that pull requests can check for a build success before they can be merged.

I realise this can be done writing some custom code and calling the github status api, but there is a checkbox for it in the edit pipeline stage. It doesn't seem to work with Github though. See this image .[image: Example of Publishing build status]

Other build tools like Bamboo have an out of the box plugin for doing this.

Comment: Hi @user205892 is my answer was the thing you were looking for? If yes please consider accepting it and upvoting letting the community focus on other open topics.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define branch policy. You can read about this on [my blog](http://thecodemanual.pl/2020/03/26/gated-check-in-build-on-azure-devops-for-dotnet-core-app.html). You need to selected existing pipeline here in GitHub settings:

[image: GitHub settings]

and then when you make PR you will get this:

[image: PR GitHub view]

You need to correctly define trigger options in your yaml file. For isntance:

- this will run for all non master branch (with each commit pushed to GitHub pipeline will run)
- for each merge to master will trigger pipeline too

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - master

pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  paths:
    include:
    - gated-checkin/*
    exclude:
    - gated-checkin/azure-pipelines.yml
```